# Column Ambiguous Error in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query below in Laravel 4. in lists, I did specified 'units.unit' but I got column ambiguous error.

```
$unit = Unit::join('bookings','bookings.unit','=','units.unit')->where('bookings.id', '=', $id)->lists('units.unit', 'units.id');
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'unit' dans field list est ambigu (SQL: select `unit`, `units`.`id` from `units` inner join `bookings` on `bookings`.`unit` = `units`.`unit` where `bookings`.`id` = 22)

Where goes wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$unit = Unit::join('bookings', 'bookings.unit', '=', 'units.unit')
            ->where('bookings.id', $id)
            ->select(
                'units.id',
                'units.unit',
                'bookings.id as bid',
                'bookings.unit as bunit'
            )
            ->lists('units.unit', 'units.id');
```

Comment: Is using a `select()` really the only way around this?

Comment: It depends, you may use `->get(['name', 'username'])`.

Comment: I just don't want to type the column names out, but it definitely works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is bug in that library. It seems that it dropped the table prefix 'unit' while translating your query to native sql.

select unit, ...  //ambiguity is between units.unit and bookings.unit columns

one would expect it to generate a statement as follows:

select units.unit, units.id from ...