# Laravel list issue

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have below query which is directly linked to drop down. However, if I `lists()` with `join()` it gives

> errors: ambiguous 'id'

Code:

```
Company::join('users', 'users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->where('companies.name', 'NOT LIKE', '%XXXX%')
                    ->lists('name', 'id');
```

What could be a solution with `lists()`? any help would be real help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column Ambiguous Error in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331201/column-ambiguous-error-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 0):

Both tables contain an `id` field. The solution here would be to prepend the table name to the id field that you want to list. For example:

```
Company::join('users', 'users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->select(
        'companies.name as companyName',
        'companies.id as companyID'
    )
    ->distinct()
    ->where('companies.name', 'NOT LIKE', '%XXXX%')
    ->lists('companyName', 'companyID');
```

Comment: it gives this: Undefined property: stdClass::$companies.id

Comment: Now I am getting Undefined property: stdClass::$companyName

Comment: Company::join('users', 'users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                    ->select(
                        'companies.name as companyName',
                        'users.id as companyID'
                    )
                    ->distinct()
                    ->where('companies.name', 'NOT LIKE', '%XXXX%')
                    ->lists('companyName', 'companyID');

Answer (score 0):

The error showing because you `id` column in both of your table. I don't know which table's id you needed. In this answer I assume you don't need the `id` of `user` so I declared it as `uid`. So, there is only one column named `id` which is belong to `companies` table.

```
Company::join('users', 'users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->distinct()
    ->where('companies.name', 'NOT LIKE', '%XXXX%')
    ->select('users.id as uid','companies.id','companies.name')
    ->lists('name', 'id');
```

Comment: I get Undefined property: stdClass::$name

Comment: Do you have `name` field in `companies` table?

Comment: Yes! I have a name field

Comment: Can you show your blade code Where you call this query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  DB::table('companies')->distinct()->join('users',function($join){
            $join->on( 'users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                ->where('companies.name', 'NOT LIKE', '% %');
        }) ->lists('companies.name');
```

P.S. works fine for me

Comment: I get Call to undefined method Laravel\Database\Query\Join::where()

Comment: DB::table('companies')->distinct()->join('users',function($join){
                            $join->on( 'users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')->where('companies.name', 'NOT LIKE', '%XXXX%');
                        })->lists('companies.name', 'companies.id');

Comment: I try it on laravel 4.2, what is your version?

Comment: I am working with laravel 3 unfortunately, the system was created using Laravel 3